# How to show ajax response into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pop up a modal which will show dynamic data comes from query. so when a user clicked related school will show into modal. I got the response but i'm not getting how can i show into that modal. any suggestion please?

Button:

```
 <a href="#." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="{{$user->id}}"  class="chooseSchoolBtn">Choose School</a>
```

Ajax :

```
$(".chooseSchoolBtn").on("click", function (argument) {
    //console.log($(this).data("id"))
    var user_id = $(this).data("id")
    var info = $.get("{{url('school-list')}}", {
        id: user_id
    });
    info.done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
});
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    // This section will come dynamically
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_school">
            <div class="selection_area">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="school_img_area" style="background-image: url(school/images/school/school1.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="school_info">
                <p class="school_name">School Name</p>
                <p class="school_description">Good School...</p>
                <p class="school_price">12$</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // dynamic section ends
</div>
```

json response :

```
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 2,
    price: "2340.00",
    name: "XYZ",
    display_image: "1510570005ajaPXajmik.png"
}, {
    id: 3,
    user_id: 2,
    price: "123.00",
    name: "ABC",
    display_image: "1510570049QZWiQUh7zY.jpg"
}
```

Comment: where user click related school is there any button will create according to json response

Comment: @User57 Check my answer. It will help you

Answer (score 1):

Just change the ajax response data

```
info.done(function(data){          
    $.each(data,function(index,value){
        $(".school_img_area").attr("style","background-image: url(school/images/school/"+value.display_image+");");
        $(".school_name").html(value.name);
        $(".school_price").html(value.price);
    });
});
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: suppose i have two json response, in that time it only shows the last value and skipped the first one

Comment: You mean multiple schools are there. Is it?? If so then, there will be multiple `div`s under each one...

Comment: How would you add `<div class="school_img_area" style="background-image: url("files/'+value.display_image+');" ></div>` 

Means for background image how would you give the url?
Suppose my directory is `localhost/userApp/public/files/456788.jpg`

Comment: @User57 You will get your current directory by using `getcwd()` function. For ex :- `getcwd() . "/files/" . image_name.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chooseSchoolBtn").on("click", function (argument) {
      //console.log($(this).data("id"))
      var user_id = $(this).data("id")
      var info=$.get("{{url('school-list')}}",{id:user_id});
        info.done(function(data){          
              $('DIV WHERE YOU WNAT TO DISPLAY ID').html(data.id);
              // repeat same for user_id, price, so on;
      });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement using `JSON` response than you will iterate through loop and append it html.

For ex -

```
var html="";
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var html +=<p>data.price</p>data.name<p>;
}
$('.appendTo').html(html);
```

Other option is in your controller method instead of return the data as JSON you can return HTML and than replace the content when you get ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".chooseSchoolBtn", function () {
        var schoolId= $(this).data('id');        
        $('#modalId').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some_url_to_get_school_info",
            data: {'sid':schoolId},
            success: function(data){ 
              $('#div_id_to_show').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Fail")
            }
        });
    });
```